# In VB, is there a way to create an instance of the current type without naming it?

Tags: vb.net, class, oop

I mean, I want to say something like:

```
class Fwacbar
  public function MakeOne() as MyClass
    return new MyClass()
  end function
end class
```

Using MyClass doesn't work, but I mean, being I'm within class Fwacbar, I want to return an instance of Fwacbar.

Okay, I could just say "new Fwacbar". My goal is that I have a bunch of similar classes and I want to be able to cut and paste and have to make minimal changes. It would be nice if I didn't have to change all the "new"s. It's not essential to be able to do this to write the program, but I was just thinking about it and if I knew a way to do it, maybe it would be more valuable elsewhere.

Comment: While there probably is a solution, I'm stuck on the why?  What's the difference between typing Dim foo = new Fwacbar and Dim foo = Fwacbar.MakeOne().  Seems like more typing and obfuscates your code

Comment: Do you have a better example? It's like you want a `Factory(Of T As {new})` without the factory. As mentioned above and as you also mentioned, this is the same as `dim inst as new Something()`

Comment: "I want to be able to cut and paste and have to make minimal changes."  But why have the same lines of code copied in multiple places? Better to design your classes and code structure to not require such copy/paste at all.

Comment: There is no good way to do what you want. There are ways, so it can be done if necessary, but there are no good ways, so don't do it if it isn't necessary. For the record, that method should be `Shared`.

Comment: @SeanSkelly Sure. It grates me having to create a bunch of classes with similar code. My co-workers have been banging out tons of these nearly-identical classes and I'm trying to push toward using more common code. I'm trying to put as much of the code as possible into a superclass.

Comment: @Hursey The real situation is that within the class there are numerous functions that have to create an instance of the class. So it's not "Fwacbar.MakeOne", it's inside Fwacbar, there's "blah blah MakeOne blah blah".

Comment: @Jay well if these classes are all similar wouldn’t a better option be to look at inheritance, interfaces and polymorphism?

Comment: @Hursey Sure, as I mentioned in response to someone else's comment, I didn't write them originally, and I'm trying to push more of the code into an interface and a utility class that operates on classes that implement the interface. But there is a bunch of code that is legitimately "close enough that we want to copy and paste, but different enough that it's not practical to re-use the same code". I could go into details but you probably don't want to see all the details of this particular project. :-)

Comment: @Jay well, from my experience sounds like you've got a fair amount of work to do either way, so maybe now might be the time to bite the bullet and do it right upfront rather that trying to shortcut it now and potentially creating yourself a bit of a headache when comes to maintaining that code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's definitely an odd request...but here you go:

```
Public Class Form1

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim f1 As New Fwacbar
        Dim f2 = f1.MakeOne
        Debug.Print("f1: " + f1.GetType.ToString)
        Debug.Print("f2: " + f2.GetType.ToString)
    End Sub

    Public Class Fwacbar

        Public Function MakeOne() As Object
            Return Me.GetType.GetConstructor(New System.Type() {}).Invoke(Nothing)
        End Function

    End Class

End Class
```

Comment: If you're assuming a parameterless constructor, and return type can be Object, why not change MakeOne to `return Activator.CreateInstance(Me.GetType)`?  Even cleaner.  (Need more context from OP to know if these two assumptions are OK.)